# Nomenclature of saturated aliphatic hetrocyclic amines with an alkyl group on the nitrogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

For example, how would I name the following amine?

[image: 1-propylpyrrolidine]

Since two of the alkyl groups on nitrogen are linked to each other (in a ring), I can't figure out what they should be called, as they don't fit into the usual alkyl (methyl/ethyl/etc.) mould.

Answer (score 6):

According to Subsection P-22.2.1 of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) of the functional parent compound is the retained name ‘pyrrolidine’, the nitrogen atom being numbered ‘1’.

[image: pyrrolidine]

Therefore, the name of the compound given in the question is ‘1-propylpyrrolidine’.

[image: 1-propylpyrrolidine]

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what you have tried and where your specific trouble is, my guess is that you are having trouble identifying the parent chain.

This molecule is a heterocyclic amine, and the entire heterocycle is the parent chain. In this case, the parent chain is called **pyrrolidine**.

[image]

Now - how would you name a pyrrolidine with an alkyl substituent on the nitrogen atom?